# Pymongo return values only as list

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The following pymongo query gives me all the values I need:

```
l=list(db.rounds.find({"current_strategy":"PPStrategy4016"},{"myFundsChange":1,"_id": 0}))

{'myFundsChange': '-0.30000000000000004'}, {'myFundsChange': '0.0'}, {'myFundsChange': '0.0'}, {'myFundsChange': '-0.040000000000000036'}, {'myFundsChange': '-0.08000000000000007'}, {'myFundsChange': '-0.20999999999999996'}, {'myFundsChange': '-0.47'}, {'myFundsChange': '0.0'},  {'myFundsChange': '0.0'}, {'myFundsChange': '-0.040000000000000036'}, {'myFundsChange': '-0.040000000000000036'}
```

But how can I tell pymongo to return me the values only as a list (without the key)?

Comment: Might be easier to post-process it like `[el['myFundsChange'] for el in db.rounds.find(...)]` though

Comment: [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the values into an array using the [`aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method.

Comment: Can't see how $group and $push will help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/. Do you have any explanation? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do it like this:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"current_strategy": "PPStrategy4016"}},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": None, 
        "myFundsChange": {"$push": "$myFundsChange"}
    }}
])
```

Then you can consume the cursor using a traditional for loop or simply.

```
for res in cursor:
    # do something with the result.
```

Note that the `Cursor` object *contains* one document here because we group by `None`