# How to retrieve only values (not keys) from a mongo collection using pymongo

Tags: pymongo

I'm a noob at python and pymongo and I've been playing around with some test scenarios.

I want to retrieve a list of employee IDs from a collection called 'employees', and then pass the IDs to a function that deletes them. The function excepts only the emp_id as a parameter.

e.g.

```
cursor=db.employees.find({},{ "emp_id":1,"_id": 0})
for doc in cursor:
    print emp_id
    find_employee_data(emp_id)
```

I've added in _id: 0 to the projection clause so that the ObjectID is not returned.  However my print output is still:

```
{u'emp_id': 1}
{u'emp_id': 2}
{u'emp_id': 3}
{u'emp_id': 4}
(etc)
```

I only want the value to be returned, not the key as well.  i.e. I'm just after 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

I figure I could do some postprocessing (possibly using the split operation) to pull out only the values, but is there a more elegant way to do this?  I (possibly overly naively) expected there to be a simpler way to do this.

(The group by _id none solution described here [Pymongo return values only as list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312333/pymongo-return-values-only-as-list) does not really work for me as it returns a 1 document cursor with an array of all the IDs and would still require post processing to split them up).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about post-processing the results from the cursor .e.g `employee_ids_for_deletion = (employee['emp_id'] for employee in cursor)`?
I am sure that mongo queries return a single value like you want. There is always some field in the result. Since you seem to deleting all employees, what's your reason for not doing this with `pymongo.Collection.delete_many()`